# What is the best way to structure our OAuth tokens for GCP

Tags: google-oauth

We have a multi-tenant setup in which we provide each of our clients (K-12 school districts). We give each of our clients a sub domain on our site. We use one API/OAuth token for all clients, but add each of their individual login callbacks to our token. We received a warning from google saying the following

> Your project abre-platform has multiple unique domains in the redirect URI and origin URLs, many of which have unrelated applications. This is in direct violation of the Google API Services: User Data Policy, which requires that projects accurately represent their identity and intent to Google and to our users when they request access to Google user data.

We're looking for guidance on the best way to set this up within google. Thanks.

We've been told by our account rep to open a support ticket. We did that and they route it to random teams (like GSuite). Eventually one of them told us the best way to get help was to ask here on SO. I find that odd, but here goes nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Let me check I understand your scenario.

1. You have a single server
2. That server is serving multiple domains (`school1.edu`, `school2.edu`, etc)
3. You are using a unique redirect url for each tenant, (`school1.edu/oauth`, `school2.edu/oauth`)
4. Google doesn't like it

What you should do is use a single redirect for your app across all tenants, (`myapp.com/oauth`). When you construct your initial auth URL, you can set a parameter called `state` which is preserved though the flow. So when Google redirects back to you, it will redirect to `myapp.com/oauth?state=school1`. Your server code at `/oauth` can then redirect to `{state}.edu/homepage`.

Comment: Alternately, you can create a separate Google Cloud Project for each domain. If you separate the state per school at the Google Cloud Project level, there is no risk of your user being automatically logged in to school2.edu if they've signed in to school1.edu.

Comment: Yes, that is our scenario. That's what we're thinking too at this point. We originally had a setup like @user2705223 describes, and google flagged it (and it was a mess to maintain), so we switched over to subdomaining everyone. Before we go redo things again, I'm looking for some official guidance that this is the correct way to go.

Comment: Yep. The key message coming from Google is that the OAuth redirect URL must be associated with the app, rather than any client domains that are being delivered by the app. Don't subdomain, or at least there is no need to subdomain. The key bit of my answer is that the **redirect is to your APP**, and then there is a secondary redirect to the client domain.